# InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter in client-server mode

Tags: java

I have to implement a client-server application without using NIO.
client send a request to server (in JSON) and then server send response.

the problem is with the response, because if the client send the request and te server don't send the response it work.

in both client and server side I use an `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`.  If I read and write in the server is ok, but if I put the `InputStreamReader` in the client for read the response the server don't read the previous request from the client.
I put some part of code

```
System.out.println("eleborazione richiesta");
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj;

    try{

        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(this.csocket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(this.csocket.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        obj =parser.parse(in);
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
        String richiesta= (String) jsonObj.get("request");
        System.out.println("qui");
        if(richiesta==null)return;
        if(richiesta.equals("register")){//REGISTRAZIONE
            ArrayList<String> parametri = null;
            JSONArray  list = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("parametri");
            if(list!=null) {
                Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
                parametri =new ArrayList<String>(list.size());
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    parametri.add(iterator.next());

                }
            }
            System.out.println("richiesta "+ richiesta + " nickname " + parametri.get(0) + " lingua " + parametri.get(1));


            if(utenti.get(parametri.get(0))!=null){
                System.out.println("utente già presente");
            }else{

                utenti.put(parametri.get(0),(new Utenti( parametri.get(0),  parametri.get(1))));
                System.out.println("aggiunto");
            }

            JSONObject object= new JSONObject();
            object.put("response","ok");
            out.write(object.toJSONString());
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("mandata risposta");


        }
...
```

client

```
SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 1234);
    Socket client =null;
    try {
        client = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("request","register");
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    list.add("nick");
    list.add("lingua");
    obj.put("parametri", list);

    try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    {
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        out.write(obj.toJSONString());
        //out.flush();
        //out.close();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object response =parser.parse(in);
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) response;
        String resp= (String) jsonObj.get("response");
        System.out.println(resp);
```

if I execute this the server print only

```
client connesso
eleborazione richiesta
```

if I remove the

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object response =parser.parse(in);
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) response;
    String resp= (String) jsonObj.get("response");
    System.out.println(resp);
```

from the client, the server can send the response, but naturally no one read this

can someone tell me what the  problem is?

Comment: have you tried debugging it?

Comment: the problem is when i use the InputStreamReader in the client (therefore when i use parser).

Comment: if I create the stream "in" but don't use it, the problem there isn't

Comment: if i use the client inputStream, i can't use the server InputStream

Comment: 'Can't use' is not a problem description. Try harder.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is your Client and server are blocked reading since it is reading until EOF. you will not receive EOF until you close the socket or close the OutPutStream. You might want to close the OutPutStream immediately after writing if it is only a one-off write.
`out.write(obj.toJSONString());
 out.flush();
 socket.shutdownOutput();`